# Preventing WPForms from going to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, wpforms

I am attempting to prevent WPForms from going to the next page until after my Ajax function has run. I am working on a multi-page form for a custom them and need to run a form validation to check if a user has already been created with that email. I could find no settings for this inside WPForms so began working on a custom Ajax function alongside a PHP function.

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Use event delegation to handle click on the "Next" button
jQuery(document).on('click', '.wpforms-page-next', function(e) {

```
        //pevent the default action of the button
        e.preventDefault();


        // Get the current page of the form
        var currentPage = jQuery(this).data('page');

        // Check if we are on the first page of the form
        if (currentPage === 1) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the email address from the form field
            var email = jQuery('#wpforms-902-field_5').val();
            console.log(email);

            // Perform your AJAX request and response handling here

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                //choose the type of request
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    //run action launching the function
                    action: 'check_email_availability',
                    //pass the email address to the function
                    email_availability: email,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response === 'unavailable') {
                        console.log('unavailable')
                        // Show an error message for duplicate email
                        jQuery('#error-message').text('This email is already in use.');

                    } else {
                        console.log('available')
                        // If email is available, proceed to the next page
                        //jQuery( '.wpforms-page-next' ).click();
                    }
                }
            })
    
        }

});
```

});
`

This is my ajax function, I have tested the function itself and it is working perfectly the only issue is that it runs after the WPForm has already gone from the first page to the second. I have successfully received both unavailable and available in the console.

Here is my php for reference.

add_action('wp_ajax_check_email_availability', 'check_email_availability');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_email_availability', 'check_email_availability');

function check_email_availability() {
global $wpdb;

```
if (isset($_POST['email_availability'])) {
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email_availability']); // Corrected the key here

    $user = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM ilearn_students WHERE email = %s",
            $email
        )
    );

    $response = $user ? 'unavailable' : 'available'; // Reversed the response here
    echo $response;
}
wp_die();
```

}

I have tried placing the e.preventDefault() in several different positions, I have tried removing the ajax and instead returning false, trying to break mine and the forms Ajax to no avail.

I have wrapped the Ajax inside a timeout function to try and ensure the ajax was read before the form moved to the next page, which also failed.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.